# Probability that a Brownian Motion in R2 hits a line through the origin.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $B_t=(B_t^1,B_t^2)$ be a Brownian motion in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I wish to show that $P[B_t^2=0, t\in(0,\epsilon)]=1$ for all $\epsilon$; that is, a Brownian motion in $\mathbb{R}^2$ will always hit a line through the origin in some short time. For context, this is part of an attempted solution for Exercise  9.7c in Oksendal's SDE book, 6th edition.

My reason for believing this is that I know that one-dimensional Brownian motion equals zero infinitely many times in a short time interval, but I'm not sure how to adapt this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If $B_t^1$ and $B_t^2$ are independent, can you just ignore $B_t^1$ and reduce this to the one-dimensional case?

Comment: Henry's comment + the fact that the whole thing is rotationally invariant will give you the answer. (i.e. you can construct another BM from these that has the same distributions but one direction is perpendicular to your line (and the other parallel))

Comment: Duh! Little embarrassed that I didn't realize this myself. Thanks!